# Selenium webdriver - element can be found but is not visible?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am working on a personal project to make a python script to log in to a site and do few tasks for me, and I've decided to use the Selenium web driver. Currently I am stuck on the log in part.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://pucatrade.com")

puca_username = "example@username"
user_fieldID = "login"

user_fieldelement = driver.find_element_by_id(user_fieldID)
user_fieldelement.send_keys(puca_username)
```

However, it gives me `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible` on the send_keys call. I know that find_element_by_id finds the element because I've tested with `print user_fieldelement.get_attribute('id'),` and it prints login. So if find_element_by_id works can find the element, how come send_keys can't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *multiple inputs having `id="login"`*. You are interested in the one located in the login form on the very right which is inside the `div` with `id="home-login"`:

```
form = driver.find_element_by_id("home-login")

# login
user_fieldelement = form.find_element_by_id(user_fieldID)
user_fieldelement.send_keys(puca_username)

# password
passwd_fieldelement = form.find_element_by_id(passwd_fieldID)
user_fieldelement.send_keys(puca_password)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. There was one more that was earlier up in the code, which has display set to none. So just to check my understanding, find_element_by_id is able to find that first `"id="login"` since it exists in the code, but since its display is set to none and cannot be interacted with, send_keys is giving me the that exception

Answer (score -1):

I'm still not sure why some websites has many fields with same name and id... but as I was only interested on the visible ones, I did this little function to get the right field.

```
    def find_visible_element_by_name(name):
        # Websites, for some reason, has many fields with the sama name and ID! This gets the first one that is visible.
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462116/selenium-webdriver-element-can-be-found-but-is-not-visible        
        fields = self.sel.find_elements_by_name(name)
        for f in fields:
            if f.is_displayed():
                return f

        return None
```

self.sel is the Selenium driver object.